# Существует ли в Python функция определения существования пути?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловые-пути

Есть ли в Python функция, которая определяет, существует ли данный путь? И если существует, будет ли она работать на всех операционных системах (например, на Android или iOS)?

Comment: Э? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists

Comment: Вроде да, спасибо.